# Broken links to code-intuit-com

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

It looks like every link to [code.intuit.com](https://code.intuit.com) is broken and redirects to the main Intuit site.

Are these code samples still available or are they gone forever?

Comment: You should submit a support ticket to Intuit about this. It's not appropriate for SO, but it *is* something that you should let Intuit know about.

Comment: code samples are now linked from the new developer.intuit.com site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sample apps are here now:
https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0055_devkits/sample_apps

thanks
Jarred